# How to separate Arabic and English text in a string value?

Tags: sql-server

I am getting data from a source like this:

> Air Passage - First Time Joining تذاكر سفر حضور لأول مره

I need to split this kind of data into two columns, English text should go into one column and Arabic text should go into the other column.

Can any one help me with this please?

Comment: regex or perhaps look at numerical value for the letters.

Comment: Is it always the same pattern: first the English part, then the Arabic part?

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be (if possible) format the data to something like this:

Air Passage - First Time Joining | تذاكر سفر حضور لأول مره

And then you just need to do an split by "|".

Answer (score 0):

REGEX

```
(?P<en>[a-zA-Z-\s]+) (?P<ar>[\w\s]+)
```

[Kiki](https://code.google.com/p/kiki-re/) is nice tool to test for multiple cases (You may need to add more characters to the ranges)

I did remove `^` and `$` to be more general case.

Answer (score 0):

USE [HRData]
GO

/***** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[StripVenNameAR]    Script Date: 1/14/2014 8:50:31 AM *****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StripVenNameAR] (@InString as NVarChar(4000))
RETURNS smallint  AS
BEGIN
    Declare @ReturnVal as smallint
    Declare @OutString as NVarchar(4000)
    Declare @Pos as smallint
    Declare @CurChar as NVarChar(1)
    SET @ReturnVal = 0

```
IF LEN(@InString) = 0                       
    SET @ReturnVal = 0                 
ELSE                        
BEGIN                       
    Set @Pos = 1                    
    SET @OutString = ' '                    
    WHILE (@Pos <= Len(@InString))                  
    BEGIN                   
        Set @CurChar =  SUBSTRING(@InString, @Pos, 1)               
        if unicode(@CurChar) between 1536 and 1791
            SET @ReturnVal = @Pos
            Set @Pos = @Pos + 1    
            if  @ReturnVal>=1
            Break
            else
            continue          
    END  
    end
```

RETURN @ReturnVal
end

GO